# gitlab when I use the link of Container Registry in the ci file, I will be prompted that the docker is not found

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "main" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event" 
      when: never
    - when: always


variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE


stages:
  - test
  - build



run_unit_tests:
  image: node:16-alpine3.17
  stage: test
  tags:
    - txy
  before_script:
    - cd app
    - npm install
  script: 
    - npm test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - app/junit.xml
    reports:
      junit: app/junit.xml


build_image:
  stage: build
  tags: 
    - remoteone
  before_script:
    - echo "Docker registry url is $CI_REGISTRY"
    - echo "Docker registry username is $CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    - echo "Docker registry repo is $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .


push_image:
  stage: build
  needs: 
    - build_image
  tags:
    - remoteone
  before_script:
    - echo "Docker registry url is $CI_REGISTRY"
    - echo "Docker registry username is $CI_REGISTRY_USER"
    - echo "Docker registry repo is $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  script: 
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIXmC.png)

correspondence of the above variables

**$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE** = docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/komorebi-cqd/mynodeapp-cicd-project .

**$CI_REGISTRY** = docker push registry.gitlab.com/komorebi-cqd/mynodeapp-cicd-project

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN apk add docker-cli

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./app/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./app .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm" ,"start"]
```

**cicd pipelines build_image error**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.5.1 (7178588d)
  on one-docker-runner fAyvKeBR
Preparing the "docker" executor
00:03
Using Docker executor with image alpine:3.14 ...
Pulling docker image alpine:3.14 ...
Using docker image sha256:dd53f409bf0bd55eac632f9e694fd190244fef5854a428bf3ae1e2b636577623 for alpine:3.14 with digest alpine@sha256:4c869a63e1b7c0722fed1e402a6466610327c3b83bdddb94bd94fb71da7f638a ...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on runner-fayvkebr-project-41046722-concurrent-0 via VM-20-2-ubuntu...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/komorebi-cqd/mynodeapp-cicd-project/.git/
Checking out 023ee3af as main...
Removing app/junit.xml
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:03
Downloading artifacts for run_unit_tests (3502740847)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=3502740847 responseStatus=200 OK token=64_pVtH2
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
Using docker image sha256:dd53f409bf0bd55eac632f9e694fd190244fef5854a428bf3ae1e2b636577623 for alpine:3.14 with digest alpine@sha256:4c869a63e1b7c0722fed1e402a6466610327c3b83bdddb94bd94fb71da7f638a ...
$ echo "Docker registry url is $CI_REGISTRY"
Docker registry url is registry.gitlab.com
$ echo "Docker registry username is $CI_REGISTRY_USER"
Docker registry username is gitlab-ci-token
$ echo "Docker registry repo is $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
Docker registry repo is registry.gitlab.com/komorebi-cqd/mynodeapp-cicd-project
$ docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
/bin/sh: eval: line 137: docker: not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

It prompts docker: not found,i have been searching the Internet for a long time, but there is no specific solution

I have a Docker installed on my server, and there is no problem running Docker PS. However, when I use the gitlab registry, I will be prompted that the Docker does not exist. I do not know where the problem is, and there is no corresponding solution online. I hope someone can tell me why the Docker is not found and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**GitLab CI** uses **Docker** to run your pipelines (with the *Docker executor*) but it doesn't mean that **Docker** will be available from inside the CI containers.

You can see from the CI output that it uses the `alpine:3.14` Docker image to run your commands, unfortunately this image has not **Docker** installed:

```bash
Using Docker executor with image alpine:3.14 ...
```

The [GitLab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) describes 3 ways to build Docker images with their CI using:

- the **Shell executor**
- **Docker-in-Docker** with the **Docker** or **Kubernetes executor**
- **Docker socket binding**

I'd say to go with the **Docker-in-Docker** approach because the other 2 may result in concurrency issues: concurrent pipelines will use the same *Docker daemon* which could result in naming collision of Docker *objects*.

---

You can read more about my **personal experience in 2020** about [building Docker images in GitLab CI](https://aymdev.io/en/blog/post/docker-image-building-on-gitlab-ci) if that helps.

Comment: I used your method, but it made another error，```error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=registry.gitlab.com%2Fkomorebi-cqd%2Fmynodeapp-cicd-project&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial tcp: lookup docker on 183.60.83.19:53: no such host```

Comment: I also tried to follow the Docker in Docker in the gitlab document, but the same error occurred

Comment: @qiaodachen this is another issue unrelated to your original question, I don't know what's wrong with your updated setup. Do you find solutions in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71657162/gitlab-runner-docker-login-not-working-error-during-connect-post-http-docker) ? If not, you can ask a new question on SO.